# change style-setter-property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, styles, setter

I have the code below is very simple with style resources in wp7,

```
<Style x:Name="image_find" x:Key="ImageFind1" TargetType="Image">
     <Setter Property="Source" Value="display/pen.png"/>
</Style>
```

I want to change the source value of setter, for ex. "display/tool.png" when I want beside runtime in code of my app, take in mind that I need image beeing in style :)

I am running something like this,

```
image_find.Setters.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, "display/tool.png");
```

or something like,

```
style = App.Current.Resources["image_find1"] as Style;    
style.Setters.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, "display/tool.png");`
```

and I am getting `NullReferenceException` and the app breaks...

Comment: Where is this style located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on where your `Style` is located, and you need to use the `x:Key` to find the Style not the `x:Name`

If the style is in your Application Resources (App.xaml) this should work

```
   var style = App.Current.Resources["ImageFind1"] as Style;
```

If its within the context of your `Window/UserControl` you will use `FindResource`

```
   var style = FindResource("ImageFind1") as Style;
```

Comment: Thanks but my style is beside <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources></phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> and with var style = App.Current.Resources["ImageFind1"] as Style; i steel getting this message the other one doesn't recognizes the FindResource.

Comment: Then try `Resources["ImageFind1"];`

Comment: I am thinking we are close, now i am getting 0x8000ffff exeption! Breaking on style.Setters.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, "display/tool.png");

Comment: Did you cast as style `Resources["ImageFind1"] as Style; `

Comment: Yes but nothing, now i found the solution after you helped me find the resource, it doesn't work the command style.Setters.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, "display/tool.png"); now i made a setter and each time i want to change image i run style.Setters.Clear(); and then style.Setters.Add(...setter...);          Thanks a lot for your help by teach me the difference of key and name and also the right place of style!

Comment: ahh.. I was just trying to figure out how you were using `SetValue` LOL. glad its all working, Good luck :)

Comment: It could be usefull to know it because i think with this method you not need to do clear and add setetr, is more fast command if the using is in the way i am thinking, but thanks again!